# apt-get upgrade always hangs at same percentage

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I am currently trying to ugprade my server system using `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`. However, the upgrade process always starts to hang at exactly 31%. First, I suspected a problem with the package it was trying to download, which was `unzip`. So I went ahead, downloaded and installed the package myself and did a `apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`. However, upon hitting 31%, the process froze again. Rinse and repeat.

I have now installed three packages manually and there is still no change.
Here is the last few lines of the output:

```
Holen: 156 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gstreamer1.0-plugins-base amd64 1.2.4-1~ubuntu2 [485 kB]
Holen: 157 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gstreamer1.0-x amd64 1.2.4-1~ubuntu2 [63,9 kB]
Holen: 158 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main python-apt amd64 0.9.3.5ubuntu2 [141 kB]
Holen: 159 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main python-libxml2 amd64 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.7 [140 kB]
Holen: 160 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main unattended-upgrades all 0.82.1ubuntu2.4 [25,9 kB]
Holen: 161 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main software-properties-common all 0.92.37.7 [9.356 B]
Holen: 162 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main python3-software-properties all 0.92.37.7 [19,1 kB]
Holen: 163 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe python-software-properties all 0.92.37.7 [19,6 kB]
31% [Wird verarbeitet]
```

Since it doesn't seem to be related to a certain package, I'm starting to run out of ideas. The system is a rented virtual server running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, I wouldn't know of any firewalls or proxies.

Can anybody help me out with this issue?

Comment: It's downloading, so just wait :) (or maybe try to change the mirrors)

Comment: I feel stupid now. Go ahead and write up a short answer, I'll mark it as correct and we can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's downloading, so just wait :)
(or maybe try to change the mirrors)